# Alternatives to McCormick Envelope

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, linear-programming, combinatorial-optimization, integer-programming, operations-research

I have an optimization problem for which I have the optimal solution obtained by the ILP.
However, when I introduced the McCormick Envelope to replace the product of a bi-linear term in its LP relaxation, after rounding the cost function value is much higher than that of the ILP.

Are there alternatives to the McCormick Envelopes to get a better cost function value after rounding or even a better approach for the bi-linear term ?